# Rerunning test case in Makefile?

Tags: c, linux, makefile

So I did a test case called basic, and I run the following command to run it:

```
make tests/basic.result
```

And the program runs and gives me the output.

The PROBLEM -->
Then I change some of the code and rerun the make command to recompile then rerun the same command and it gives me:

```
make: `tests/basic.result' is up to date.
```

Why isn't it rerunning and giving me different output ?

Comment: Because you haven't defined its dependencies correctly.

Comment: This question cannot be answered without looking at relevant pieces of your Makefile but I assume @OliCharlesworth is right.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth you mean the make.src file ?

Comment: we need your makefile contents to be able to answer this question, so please post the makefile contents.